# Atheros AR9485 12.04 wifi problem not solved by hwcrypt

Tags: 12.04, wireless, acer, aspire-one, ath9k

Following a routine update to Ubuntu 12.04, my wireless no longer works - it is constantly seeking a connection but not accepting my password.

This has been documented elsewhere, with a fix involving file creation:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

with contents:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

followed by reboot.

However, I have tried this fix with no success, and I can't find any other solutions.

This using 12.04.1 32-bit on an Acer D270-26Dkk.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the output from the following command: `dmesg | egrep '\<ath\>|ath9k'`

Comment: Have tried, but output is 36,000 characters too long to post. egrep command didn't work at all.

Comment: then use [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/). Maybe it's a driver bug.

Comment: hope this helps! <http://paste.ubuntu.com/1640045/

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me on Acer Aspire V5

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1 blink=1 btcoex_enable=1
```

in:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

even if this folder doesn't exist, you may create it.